# Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'camera_avfoundation' not found error when running production flutter build on ios real device

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, environment

Recently I created a separate firebase project to have a production and staging environment for my Flutter project. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhm1Cv2uPko) youtube video to set up my xcode schemes (staging & prod) and project along the way. But now when I attempt to run the production build of my app on my device I get the following error:

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'camera_avfoundation' not found
```

The staging build runs fine.